# How do I escape these characters for a DistinguishedName in c#

Tags: c#, escaping

I am writing a c# application to enumerate a list of Active Directory (AD) Organizational Units (OUs). As input, I pass in the `DistinguishedName` (DN). A DN, for those not familiar is like a FQDN but for a specific object in the AD. Everything works as expected except in the case that the DN contains the characters + and /.

The sub that handles the enumeration passes an error, I'm guessing because the characters have not been escaped. How can I ensure that the **OUPath** path variable escapes all the characters mentioned in this link: http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm plus "/" ? - Thanks

```
    String OUPath = textBox1.text;
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + OUPath);
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);

    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

    var result = searcher.FindAll();
```

Edit. Finally solved it. I was going about it the wrong way. The characters to escape are not ones in the DN per say but rather within the individual OU names, meaning I had to split them and deal with them separately before joining the string again. The below function does exactly what I need. The leading and trailing whitespace requirement applies to the DN string as a whole and is handled elsewhere. Special thanks to afrogonabike.

```
private string escapeOUNameCharacters(string DN) //in ou names
    {
        DN = DN.Replace(txtLDAPPath.Text, "");
        DN = DN.TrimEnd(',');

        string[] OUNames = DN.Split(',');

        string escapedOUNamesInDNPath = "";
        string escapedOUName = "";            

        foreach (string s in OUNames)
        {
            escapedOUName = s.Replace("OU=", "");

            const string escapeChars = @"\";
            const string chars = @",\#+<>;""=";

            //escape the chars that need to be escaped
            foreach (char ch in chars)
            {
                escapedOUName = escapedOUName.Replace(ch.ToString(), escapeChars + ch);
            }

            //custom escape dictionary example:
            var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {@"/", @"\2F"}};
                                                                //,{@"\", @"\5C"}}; 
            foreach (var pair in replacements)
            {
                escapedOUName = escapedOUName.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            escapedOUNamesInDNPath = escapedOUNamesInDNPath + "OU=" + escapedOUName + ",";            
        }
        escapedOUNamesInDNPath = escapedOUNamesInDNPath + txtLDAPPath.Text;          

        return escapedOUNamesInDNPath;            
    }
```

Comment: You can use `string.Replace()` to create a copy of your `OUPath` string, replacing `@"+"` with `@"\+"` and so on.  But what is in your `OUPath` string?  If it already contains [comma separated  components](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-path.htm), then it will be difficult to know what to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided it states that you must escape leading and trailing white space also (but not embedded whitespace). Here's a simple function that would do what you need. Tweak as required:

```
private static string Escape( string s )
{
    const string escapeChars = "\\";
    const string chars = @"/,#+<>;""=";
    string ret = s;

    ret = ret.Replace(escapeChars, escapeChars + escapeChars);

    //escape the chars that need to be escaped
    foreach (char ch in chars)
    {
        ret = ret.Replace(ch.ToString(), escapeChars + ch);
    }

    //escape leading white space
    int whiteSpaceCount = 0;
    while (whiteSpaceCount < ret.Count() && Char.IsWhiteSpace(ret[whiteSpaceCount]))
    {
        ret = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ret.Substring(0, whiteSpaceCount), escapeChars,
            ret.Substring(whiteSpaceCount));
        whiteSpaceCount += 1 + escapeChars.Length;
    }

    //escape trailing whitespace
    if (whiteSpaceCount < ret.Count())
    {
        whiteSpaceCount = ret.Count() -1;
        while (whiteSpaceCount >= 0 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(ret[whiteSpaceCount]))
        {
            ret = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ret.Substring(0, whiteSpaceCount), escapeChars,
                ret.Substring(whiteSpaceCount));
            whiteSpaceCount--;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Or for a more generic replace char a with sequence b and char c with sequence d function:

```
private static string Escape( string s )
{
    var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {@"\", @"\5C"},
                                                          {@"*", @"\2A"},
                                                          {@"(", @"\2B"},
                                                          {@")", @"\29"},
                                                          {@"/", @"\3C"}};
    string ret = s;

    //escape the chars that need to be escaped
    foreach (var pair in replacements)
    {
        ret = ret.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    var whiteSpaceEscapeChars = @"\";
    //escape leading white space
    int whiteSpaceCount = 0;
    while (whiteSpaceCount < ret.Count() && Char.IsWhiteSpace(ret[whiteSpaceCount]))
    {
        ret = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ret.Substring(0, whiteSpaceCount), whiteSpaceEscapeChars,
            ret.Substring(whiteSpaceCount));
        whiteSpaceCount += 1 + whiteSpaceEscapeChars.Length;
    }

    //escape trailing whitespace
    if (whiteSpaceCount < ret.Count())
    {
        whiteSpaceCount = ret.Count() -1;
        while (whiteSpaceCount >= 0 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(ret[whiteSpaceCount]))
        {
            ret = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ret.Substring(0, whiteSpaceCount), whiteSpaceEscapeChars,
                ret.Substring(whiteSpaceCount));
            whiteSpaceCount--;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly except for "/". Can you think of a reason why?

Comment: Example input string: 

OU=+B Online/Entity Group Address,OU=SEA BA Access Groups,OU=GROUPS,OU=SGSIN01,OU=SG,OU=SEA - South East Asia,DC=XYZ,DC=CONTOSO,DC=NET

Comment: I found the following comment on the web:

"The escape sequence substitute for the forward slash is \2f. The escape sequence substitute for the backward slash is \5c. To retrieve the organizational unit named /Charlotte\ using the LDAP Search Filter and the [ADSISearcher] type accelerator, we can use a query that looks like the following.

PS C:\> ([ADSISearcher]"name=\2fCharlotte\5c").FindAll() | Select Path" 

---Not sure how to apply it

Comment: I've removed the escape char from the chars string (see above) and replace this first. This works for all "\" and "/" examples I've tried. I'm not familiar with the actual usage of the string that you're talking about so I can't help any further I'm afraid. The above function can be changed to do what you want once you've worked out what you actually need. I'm happy to adjust it if you can work out what the actual rules are.

Comment: I've just added another function that will replace individual chars with whatever sequences you like. Just amend the dictionary to suit

Comment: Another thought have you tried not escaping the "/"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `@` character before any string to ignore any escape character that it may contains:

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + OUPath);
```

EDIT:

You can also use `@` in front of OUPath like this: `@OUPath`

Comment: This will have no effect. `//` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Yes for the // it will not need the @ character. But it can be used for @OUPath or any String

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `+` and `/` characters like so:

```
path = path.Replace("+", "\\+");
path = path.Replace("/", "\\/");
```

Then use the escaped path.

There are other characters you need to escape like this; see http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm for a list.